# Inconsistent enum display when new members are added

Tags: c#, enums, .net-4.0

I have the following enum declaration

```
enum Vehicle1
{
    None,
    Bicycle,
    //Motorcycle,
    //Car,
    //Van,
    //Lorry,
    //Aeroplane,
    //Rocket,
    //TimeMachine,

    Basikal = Bicycle,
    Fahrrad = Basikal,
    Velo = 1,
}

enum Vehicle3
{
    None,
    Bicycle,
    Motorcycle,
    Car,
    //Van,
    //Lorry,
    //Aeroplane,
    //Rocket,
    //TimeMachine,

    Basikal = Bicycle,
    Fahrrad = Basikal,
    Velo = 1,
}
```

When I used the following to print out the output,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Bicycle, Vehicle1.Bicycle));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Basikal, Vehicle1.Basikal));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Fahrrad, Vehicle1.Fahrrad));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Velo, Vehicle1.Velo));      
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle3.Bicycle, Vehicle3.Bicycle));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle3.Basikal, Vehicle3.Basikal));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle3.Fahrrad, Vehicle3.Fahrrad));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle3.Velo, Vehicle3.Velo));
```

I get the following output at the console:

```
1: Basikal
1: Basikal
1: Basikal
1: Basikal
1: Fahrrad
1: Fahrrad
1: Fahrrad
1: Fahrrad
```

The only different between these two enum declarations that I can observe is that Vehicle3 has more member defined. The underlaying value for Vehicle1.Bicycle and Vehicle3.Bicycle are the same, i.e. 1, but why are the output differ?

Comment: What did you expect to occur?

Comment: @code4life, I'm studying the behavior of enum and expecting the output to be the same regardless of the number of members defined in a enum declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been stated in [MSDN page for Enum.ToString - Remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you
>   attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration
>   member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make
>   any assumptions about which name the method will return. For example,
>   the following enumeration defines two members, Shade.Gray and
>   Shade.Grey, that have the same underlying value.

```
enum Shade {
     White = 0, Gray = 1, Grey = 1, Black = 2  }
```

The following method call attempts to retrieve the name of a member of the Shade

> enumeration whose underlying value is 1. The method can return either
>   "Gray" or "Grey", and your code should not make any assumptions about
>   which string will be returned.
>
> `string shadeName = ((Shade) 1).ToString("F");`

Note that `string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Bicycle, Vehicle1.Bicycle)` is basically
`string.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)Vehicle1.Bicycle, Vehicle1.Bicycle.ToString())`

Answer (score 0):

> but why are the output differ?

You can use the ILSpy tool or other similar tool to see how the Enum.ToString() method is impelemented.

I've made a quick look at it. It seams that in the end it gets to Type.GetEnumName method. Looking at this method in ILSpy, it seems that first, .NET gets all possible value names of the enum type (via Type.GetEnumNames), and then does a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for the value (1 in your example).

In your example, here is the result of `typeof(Vehicle1).GetEnumNames()`:

```
[0]: "None"
[1]: "Bicycle"
[2]: "Basikal"
[3]: "Fahrrad"
[4]: "Velo"
```

And the result of `typeof(Vehicle3).GetEnumNames()`:

```
[0]: "None"
[1]: "Velo"
[2]: "Bicycle"
[3]: "Fahrrad"
[4]: "Basikal"
[5]: "Motorcycle"
[6]: "Car"
```

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getenumnames(v=vs.110).aspx), when more than one enum item has the same value, the order is unspecified.

So binary search stars in the middle. For Vehicle1, it will start with Basikal, and for Vehicle3 it will start with Fahrrad. Search stops immediatly since the value in both cases is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is due to some enum members have same value.
ToString() result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of answers are already explaining the reason behind the behavior in your question.

Good place would be to analyze the System.Enum implementation. Here is a link to the Microsoft [Reference Resources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs) (please note that this is pointing to .NET Framework 4.6)

If you do a walk thorough

1) `GetName` method

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public static String GetName(Type enumType, Object value)
    {
        if (enumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumType");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        return enumType.GetEnumName(value);
    }
```

2) Dive into `enumType.GetEnumName(value)`

```
    public virtual string GetEnumName(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

        if (!IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnum"), "enumType");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        Type valueType = value.GetType();

        if (!(valueType.IsEnum || Type.IsIntegerType(valueType)))
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeEnumBaseTypeOrEnum"), "value");

        Array values = GetEnumRawConstantValues();
        int index = BinarySearch(values, value);

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            string[] names = GetEnumNames();
            return names[index];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

3) Focus on these 2 lines

```
Array values = GetEnumRawConstantValues();
int index = BinarySearch(values, value);
```

3.1) `GetEnumRawConstantValues` method

```
    private Array GetEnumRawConstantValues()
    {
        string[] names;
        Array values;
        GetEnumData(out names, out values);
        return values;
    }
```

3.1.1) `GetEnumData` method

```
    // This will return enumValues and enumNames sorted by the values.
    private void GetEnumData(out string[] enumNames, out Array enumValues)
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<String[]>(out enumNames) != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn<Array>(out enumValues) != null);

        FieldInfo[] flds = GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        object[] values = new object[flds.Length];
        string[] names = new string[flds.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < flds.Length; i++)
        {
            names[i] = flds[i].Name;
            values[i] = flds[i].GetRawConstantValue();
        }

        // Insertion Sort these values in ascending order.
        // We use this O(n^2) algorithm, but it turns out that most of the time the elements are already in sorted order and
        // the common case performance will be faster than quick sorting this.
        IComparer comparer = Comparer.Default;
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            string tempStr = names[i];
            object val = values[i];
            bool exchanged = false;

            // Since the elements are sorted we only need to do one comparision, we keep the check for j inside the loop.
            while (comparer.Compare(values[j - 1], val) > 0)
            {
                names[j] = names[j - 1];
                values[j] = values[j - 1];
                j--;
                exchanged = true;
                if (j == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (exchanged)
            {
                names[j] = tempStr;
                values[j] = val;
            }
        }

        enumNames = names;
        enumValues = values;
    }
```

3.2) `BinarySearch` method

```
private static int BinarySearch(Array array, object value)
    {
        ulong[] ulArray = new ulong[array.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            ulArray[i] = Enum.ToUInt64(array.GetValue(i));

        ulong ulValue = Enum.ToUInt64(value);

        return Array.BinarySearch(ulArray, ulValue);
    }
```

From 3.1.1 and 3.2 you can see that the enum values are being sorted (insertion sort) in ascending order and then a binary search is performed on the result array for the value.

Answer (score -2):

c# enums when cast to integers are zero index based (unless explicitly set).  Thus in your example Velo equal 1 which means it equals and existing item (Bicycle).

Think of them like this:

```
enum Vehicle1
    {
        None = 0,
        Bicycle = 1,
        //Motorcycle = 2,
        //Car = 3,
        //Van = 4,
        //Lorry = 5,
        //Aeroplane = 6,
        //Rocket = 7,
        //TimeMachine = 8,

        Basikal = Bicycle,//set to 1
        Fahrrad = Basikal, // also set to 1
        Velo = 2, // this is explictitly set as 2, becuase of the commented items above, otherwise the auto index would be 9
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to not explicitly set Velo = 1, and its underlaying value is defaulted to 2 (instead of 9 as mentioned on your code comment) because it is incremented by 1 from its preceding enum value.